# how to remove the cursor from an editView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have up to 4 edit views (amount changes dynamically) in a linearLayout

how can I set the cursor to appear in none of them at the beginning?

This activity ignores onConfigurationChange and i want to de-select previous user choice.

meaning in the onCreate i want to de-select all of them.

I have tried this:

```
  findViewById(R.id.editText1).setSelected(false);
```

for each of them, but the cursor stayed.

I want the curser appear again when the user clicks but then disappear again onCreate (after screen rotation till another user click)

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in your manifest for each activity in which you do not want focus for the edit text at the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.editText1).setCursorVisible(false);
```

this will make the caret not visible, even if the edit text is enabled, selected and being edited

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

in your manifest for each activity in which you do not want focus for the edit text at the start.

Comment: I want the curser appear again when the user clicks but then disappear again onCreate (after screen rotation till another user click)

Comment: Just try the above and see if it meets your needs.

Comment: the thing is that this activity ignores onConfigurationChange and i want to de-select previous user choice.

Comment: Remove the onConfigChanges tag, it depends on how you want to use it.